# Custom UserDetailsService is not called by spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to use `UserDetailsService` in `spring-security` to implement my authentication logic. However, `UserDetailsService` is not called during an HTTP request. Here is the code:

```java
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userId) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> user = userService.getById(Long.parseLong(userId));
        if (user.isEmpty()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + userId + " not found");
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.get().getName(),
                user.get().getHashedPassword(),
                List.of());
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {  // (2)
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/add", "/user/loginByEmail").permitAll() // (3)
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

I use a test to test the authentication logic, here is the core of the test code:

```java
MvcResult addMvcResult = mockMvc.perform(post("/habit/friend/addById")
                .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.httpBasic("Joey", "password"))
                .contentType("application/json")
                .content(StringUtils.toJSONString(addFriendRequestByIdDTO)))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andReturn();
```

The log shows that the authentication header is inserted by spring-test:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /habit/friend/addById
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"47", Authorization:"Basic Sm9leTpwYXNzd29yZA=="]
             Body = {
  "currentUserId" : 1,
  "friendUserId" : 2
}
    Session Attrs = {org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN=org.springframework.security.web.csrf.DefaultCsrfToken@3a48c398}
```

However, the authentication failed, I got a 403, and `CustomUserDetailsService` is never called. Why?

Comment: as pointed out in the answers this is probably CORS. Also `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated in the latest version of spring security. And `configure` method is not needed you dont have to set the password encoder and userdetailsservice manually if you just provide them as beans. Please read the Spring Security documentation as you seem to be following an outdated tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be with CSRF rather than with UserDetailsService's implementation not being registered, Starting from Spring 4.x, CSRF protection is enabled by default and unless you turn it off like

```
http
    .csrf()
    .disable()
```

you are going to get 403 errors.

Comment: Yes, that's the reason, I've been searching for the answer for the whole day, thanks so much!